# C# Inherited class with a different base class's derived properties

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

Please excuse me if you find the title bad. My problem is I have a base class `A` with a property `x`. I have a derived class `A'` with property `x'`. And when I implement it looks more like below.

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public List<Part> Parts {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public void GetParts()
    {
        this.Parts.Foreach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Name));
    }
}

public class Part
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Place {get; set;}
}

public class CarPart : Part
{
    public string Setting {get; set;}
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public new List<CarPart> Parts {get; set;}
}
```

When I implement the above classes, while accessing the property parts, I'm only able to access with respect to the object identifier only.
For example in the below code :

```
var xuv300 = new Car();
xuv300.GetParts();
```

Nothing gets printed though I add the parts to `xuv300`. Because there are two different properties and base class represented Parts property doesn't have any values.

Please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Get rid of the property in the `Car` class? Why do you _need_ to hide the inherited member?

Comment: and possibly make `Vehicle` generic. i.e. `class Vehicle<T> where T:Part {... List<T> Parts {get; set;}...}` and `Car : Vehicle<CarPart>`

Comment: the new modifier hides the property in your base class, so, introducing a "brand new" property with the same name will result in a empty string, because your base class don't care about your new field.

Comment: You seem to be missing the implementation piece, where you set "Parts" property, with a list of parts. Perhaps you forgot to add the code in the example. As is, there are no parts to print. Aka write down everything i put in the following quotes ... ""